# Choosing a language

Tags: smart-contracts

I want to start using `Tezos` and one of the problems that I found as opposite to `Ethereum` where `Solidity` highlights, is that seems to be a lot of options to start writing contracts.

I've been researching the current status of the languages suggested by the official page in `tezos` and I have created a comparison table among them:

```
|       -        |       Ligo       |  SmartPy   |       Morley       |        Fi        |     Liquidity      |
|----------------|------------------|------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
| type_Strength  | Statically typed | Dynamic    | Sames as Michelsol | Statically typed | Sames as Michelsol |
| Lang_ref       | Pascal/Ocaml     | Python     | Haskell            | Js/Solidity      | Ocaml/ReasonML     |
| Compiler       | CLI              | IDE Online | CLI                | IDE Online       | CLI and IDE Online |
| Editor         | VSCode Ext.      | none       | Lorentz EDSL       | none             | none               |
| Version/Status | Next             | Alpha      | 0.3.0.1            | Alpha            | 1.0.1              |
| Documentation  | Very good        | Very Poor  | Good               | Good             | Excellent           |
| Examples       | Yes              | Few        | Few                | not found        | Yes                |
```

In my opinion, based in the information that I could obtain from the repositories and official pages, I think that, currently, the best options to start writing smart contract are with `Ligo` and `Liquidity`. Both seems to have a solid commitment with the project, with active repositories and good documentation.

I would like to hear your opinions, what language are you using and the strengths and weaknesses you have detected so far.

Comment: Hi, StackExchange is not a place to ask people's opinions.  Please check https://tezos.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hi, welcome to TSE and thanks for taking the time to formulate your question. However just asking for broad opinions is not very suited for Stack Exchange as there is not a very a high change that any single answer is "correct". It would be better that you make your question more specific please (perhaps indicate what specifically you want to write) to help the community guide you.